# How do you make Entity framework 6 + Sqlite + code first work?

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite

I am trying to create a simple project to explore how Entity framework 6 code first with sqlite db provider works, but when I complite my app I get the error:

> "The Entity Framework provider type
>   'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.Linq,
>   Version=1.0.91.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139'
>   registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider
>   with invariant name 'System.Data.SQLite' could not be loaded. Make
>   sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is
>   available to the running application. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information."

I think that this error has something to do with the app.config file.
Does anyone has a working app.config file for Entity framework 6 + Sqlite 1.0.91?

These are my config file contents:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>

  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.Linq, Version=1.0.91.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BloggingContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\animals.sqlite" providerName="System.Data.SQLite"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite"/>
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description="Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>


<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174212/entity-framework-6-with-sqlite-3-code-first-wont-create-tables

Answer (score 2):

Firstly remove the below line from the providers section :

```
<provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.Linq, Version=1.0.91.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139"/>
```

And add below line instead of that :

```
<provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.Linq" />
```

For more info : [Problems using Entity Framework 6 and SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460357/problems-using-entity-framework-6-and-sqlite)

Comment: Thank you Sampath, I made the changes but I am still getting the same error message. The project in question is here: http://www.sendspace.com/file/ovdxly

Comment: @YiannisMpourkelis Please check this link also :https://github.com/Aimeast/GitCandy/issues/3

Comment: This link is not for the same problem. However I tried some of the things discussed there but without success. If someone has a simple working console or WPF app with working SQLite 1.0.91 code first and upload it will help

Comment: Looks like there are same problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good article for this issue:
http://hintdesk.com/sqlite-with-entity-framework-code-first-and-migration/

After reading it my consolusion is: "No, please do not use sqlite if you want EF + code first". Use SQL CE instead even though it's deprecating.