# sqlite EF6 code first not creating tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, ef-code-first

I'm trying to run sqlite in memory to run my integration tests against the database. 
But I keep getting error message mentioning the tables are not created by code first. 
I did not find any clue mentioning sqlite ef6 nuget package can or can not do this. 
If not, what would be other options you recommend for in memory databases.
I would be thankful if you help.

Answer (score 1):

Check the answer at : [Entity Framework 6 with SQLite 3 Code First - Won't create tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174212/entity-framework-6-with-sqlite-3-code-first-wont-create-tables)

---

Btw, there is a `nuget` package available for `SQLite` : [Here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.EF6)

To Install package :

```
Install-Package System.Data.SQLite.EF6
```