# file based SQLite with EF6 NOT NULL Constraint failed on Insert

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, sqlite

I want to create a program that can be used just with the .exe so I needed to create a file based database from inside my program. I'm trying to use SQLite with Entity Framework so I set up following classes:

## Program.cs

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
        {
            context.Documents.Add(new Document() { Id = 1, CategoryId = 2, Description = "test", Keywords = "test,TEST,", Text = "TEST test Test" });
            Console.WriteLine(context.Documents.Single(x => x.Id == 1).Text);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}

class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}

class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Keywords { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

upon running the code it throws me this exception:

```
Unable to complete operation. The supplied SqlConnection does not specify an initial catalog or AttachDBFileName
```

But I specified the Connection string properly as far as I can tell in my app.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyContext" connectionString="Data Source=db.sqlite" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I've tried setting up the DB on my own in the Context Constructor (using `SQLiteConnection` and `SQLiteCommand`), but even though it creates the db and table successfully EF still gives me the same error. It doesn't create the file when I comment out the constructor.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: I don't know much about SQLite. But is it possible that your need to give the exact path to the db file?.
Have the information from: https://damienbod.com/2015/08/30/asp-net-5-with-sqlite-and-entity-framework-7/ and https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite/

Comment: Everything in the config file is geared to SQL Server. Did you install a Sqlite connector through NuGet?

Comment: @GertArnold yes, I tried both `Microsoft.Data.SQLite` and `System.Data.SQLite`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `System.Data.SQLite` instad of `System.Data.SqlClient`. The provider will use Microsoft's managed SQLite wrapper project, `Microsoft.Data.SQLite` rather than the `System.Data.SQLite` project.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyContext"
      connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|db.sqlite"
      providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Add this constructor to you DB context class because sometime default constructor didn't work properly.

```
public MyDBContext()
: base("MyContext")
{

}
```

Hopefully it works for you.

Comment: in the connection string, is `|DataDirectory|` some kind of variable? How do I set it? right now I'm just specifying `Data Source=db.sqlite` because to be honest right now I don't really care where the file is stored.

Comment: I added the constructor, and I specified an ´initial catalog´ in the connection string. I'm using ´System.Data.SQLite´ package from NuGet. I get following error: ´This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection´

Comment: Just put the directory where you have to store your DB Or let it if you have to store into debug directory.

Comment: Why are you using EF 6? You can do the same thing with EF Core very easily.

Comment: I can? But the NuGet package `System.Data.SQLite` automatically installs EF6. Should I just install EF Core as well? I can't uninstall EF6.

also now it seems to think I'm using SQL Server.... the error now is something about it not being able to connect to SQL Server..

Comment: oh, or should I use EF Core with the `Microsoft.Data.SQLite` package?

Comment: EF Core have its own database provider. Please see this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/

Comment: I use EF Core 1.0 with SQLite3 in windows forms application 2 years ago. Still its working fine for me.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started Here is complete documentation to use EF Core with SQLite.

Comment: I'm working on the link you sent, me, thanks btw. But do I need to specify anything in connection string provider name attribute in app.config?

Comment: No. In EF Core you do not need to specify any connection string into .config file. You just need to specify you DB file into your DB Context.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180190/discussion-between-habib-and-lenny).

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string is incomplete.

```
<add name="MyContext" connectionString="data source=db.sqlite;initial catalog=XXXXXXXXXXXX" providerName="System.Data.SQLite"/>
```

The initial catalog should contain your database name. The data source is just the instance name.

Comment: Now I recieve this error: `This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection` How do I get credentials for master database? I never set them

Comment: Change connection string to 

connectionString="data source=db.sqlite;initial catalog=XXXXXXXXXXXX;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"

Comment: It seems to think I want to use SQL Server... how exactly does EF figure out the data provider class?

Comment: Check out this link. I think this may help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38557170/simple-example-using-system-data-sqlite-with-entity-framework-6
You may want to concentrate on the connection string used.

Comment: I'm using EF Core now, and it works flawlessly. Thanks for the effort though