# Asp.net core - no such table: AspNetUsers

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

So im trying to implment user login for my a asp.net core application. Im following the microsoft tutorial [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/identity.html). I have two contexts, one called SchoolContext for saving all the school related models, and another context called ApplicationDbContext for the Account models. This is all being saved to a sqlite database. 
Everything works fine, up until I try to register a user to my context. When I try to register a user i get, cant find AspNetUsers table error. If I look in the database I don’t see the AspNetUser table. I tried adding [migrations](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/data/ef-mvc/migrations.html), but i still get that same error. Why is the table not being created ?

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup {
        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env) {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
            // Add Context services
            services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MainConnection")));
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MainConnection")));

            // Add Identify servies 
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            // Add framework services
            services.AddMvc();
        }
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, SchoolContext context) {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();
            // Config hot module replacement
            if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions {
                    HotModuleReplacement = true
                });
            }
            else {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            // Enabled Identity
            app.UseIdentity();
            // Confgure routes 
            app.UseMvc(routes => {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                    name: "spa-fallback",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            });
            // Initialize school database [FOR TESTING] 
            DbInitializer.Initialize(context);
        }
    }
```

ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
namespace ContosoUniversity.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options): base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
}
```

ApplicationUser.cs

```
namespace ContosoUniversity.Models
{
    // Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the ApplicationUser class
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
    }
}
```

appsettings.json

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MainConnection": "Data Source=/home/Josn/AspNetCore/ContosoUniversity/Databases/database.db"
  },
```

Error

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryCompilationContextFactory[1]
      An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query.
      Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: AspNetUsers'.
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Interop.MarshalEx.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, Sqlite3Handle db)
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>d__53.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.<ExecuteAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable.AsyncEnumerator.<MoveNext>d__8.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.<_FirstOrDefault>d__82`1.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.TaskResultAsyncEnumerable`1.Enumerator.<MoveNext>d__3.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.<MoveNext>d__5.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Not sure if this is resolved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174212/entity-framework-6-with-sqlite-3-code-first-wont-create-tables

Comment: @SteveGreene I dont think so, the SchoolContext tables are initiated.

Comment: Do you see a [Users] table? In my case I am even able to write to the Users table in one request but the next request tries to read from AspNetUsers

Comment: Nevermind, I was missing the call to base.OnModelCreating(builder);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you forgot to call `update-database` in the package manager console. That's what actually applies the migrations you create to your connected database(s).

The other issue may be with how you updated the table name(s). If you edited the migrations directly, it has no way to know that you changed the name at run-time and will still look for the default named tables.

To change the user table name, you want to do something like this in your DB context in the `OnModelCreating` method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating( ModelBuilder builder ) {
    base.OnModelCreating( builder );
    // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
    // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
    // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>() //Use your application user class here
           .ToTable( "ContosoUsers" ); //Set the table name here
}
```

You'll then want to create a migration to make sure everything is updated by running the following in the package manager console:

`add-migration RenamedUserTable`

Then run a quick `update-database` and try again.

Comment: I had to delete the databases and then call update database. Thanks. 
dotnet ef database update -c ApplicationDbContext

Comment: So this might be my problem, maybe you can help clearify if this is it or not. I changed the Migration table names from AspNetUsers to ContosoUsers. I tried searching in the project to see if AspNetUsers was still being used anywhere, but its not. So i dont know why identity is searching for AspNetUsers instead of ContosoUsers.

Comment: What did you do to change it?

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I did the migration command, and went into the migration cs files and changed the names in there. The database shows that the names changed.

Comment: I don't think you can do it that way. Then, the model won't know that you've changed the table name. I think you'll have to change it in the db context `OnModelCreating`. See here: http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling/relational/tables.html

Comment: I dont even know why it searching for AspNetUser. All my dbContext info is in the class listed above.

Comment: I updated my answer to include some more info based on these comments. Hopefully that should resolve it.

Comment: @John You inherit your context from IdentityDbContext. It contains a DbSet for users. Those users map by default to a table called AspNetUsers. You should not be modifying the migration to something the model doesn't expect.

Comment: @juunas Oh, now it makes sense. So i have to edit  the default idenityDbContext. Okay ill give that a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting same issue which I fixed by providing table name in OnModelCreating method.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            string SQLLiteConnectionString = @"Data Source=C:/Projects/ArticlesDB.db";
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(SQLLiteConnectionString);             
        }
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Articles>().ToTable("Articles");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Articles>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.Id).IsRequired();
            });
        }
```