# SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: AspNetUsers'

Tags: entity-framework-core, blazor-webassembly

Im creating Identity database. When trying to add new user with UserManager in ApiController, i am having the error message

**Context**

```
public partial class UsersContext : IdentityDbContext<KozelUser> {

    private readonly DbContextOptions _options;
    public UsersContext(DbContextOptions<UsersContext> options) : base(options) {
        _options = options;
    }
    public UsersContext()
    {
        
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<KozelUser>().ToTable("KozelUsers");
    }

}
```

I`ve followed this [Asp.net core - no such table: AspNetUsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39835241/asp-net-core-no-such-table-aspnetusers) question but in Migrations the table of KozelUser is still called AspNetUsers

**Designer migration**

```
modelBuilder.Entity("KozelUser", b =>
    {
       *other properties*

        b.ToTable("AspNetUsers", (string)null);
    });
```

**Update**
Okay, the table was renamed, but it still doesnt work
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: KozelUsers'.