# System.data.Sqlite with EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I'm working on a project that involves connecting SQLite with EF 6 in a database-first approach. I've installed System.Data.SQLite (and ensured that their DLLs were in the GAC), and added the dependencies to my project using NuGet. However, when I attempt to create a schema (via the Entity Data Model Wizard) for an already-existing database, I get the error

> Your project references the latest version of Entity Framework; however, an Entity Framework database provider compatible with this version could not be found for your data connection. Exit this wizard, install a compatible provide, and rebuild your project before performing this action.

I've tried the answers in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21757843/system-data-sqlite-1-0-91-0-and-ef6-0-2), but the fixes that did not involve creating the DAO classes by hand do not seem to help. Since the database that I'm connecting to is quite large (schema-wise), recreating the schema in code is not reasonable for me.

My App.config follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6, Version=1.0.91.0, Culture=neutral" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6, Version=1.0.91.0, Culture=neutral" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
        <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
        <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
        <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

I don't entirely understand what VS is complaining about, as it appears that System.Data.SQLite has properly bound itself into VS, and that the config file contains the requisite information to allow VS to find it to access the DB. However, I missed something, and I can't figure out what.

Comment: I've just started to encounter the same problem. Does anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: I'm hitting this too, anyone get it working?

Comment: Same problem here.  Any help???

Comment: What version of Sqlite and EF do you use? Why did you register Sqlite assemblies in GAC? That's not recommended because may cause conflicts with other apps.

Comment: 1.0.91.0, according to the XML file.

I register the assemblies in the GAC to ensure that they were loaded in a big-hammer kind of way. It did actually let VS go further than it did otherwise, but this was rather a long time ago and I don't remember exactly what it fixed.

Comment: The latest version is [1.0.92](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.EF6/). Did you try the NuGet package?

Comment: Please remove ", Version=1.0.91.0, Culture=neutral" from providers and try it.

Comment: We were using 1.0.92.0 and it still didn't work.  Our only solution was to use EF5, and use the two NuGet packages for Core and Linq with SQLite.

Comment: Still having the same issue with EF 6.1.0 and 1.0.92.

Comment: Anybody have the solution for EF6 ?

Comment: Maybe my answer to a similar question can offer some help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089346/database-first-create-entity-framework-6-1-1-model-using-system-data-sqlite-1-0

Answer (score 3):

This is my application configuration that was successful for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

[THIS](https://github.com/damienbod/AnimalMarketEnginsSqliteDb/blob/master/AnimalMarketDal/App.config) project also references an identical configuration to my own.