# Visual Studio 2013 say me Entity framework that the provider of SQLite is not found

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, sqlite, dataprovider

I had a project that it uses entity framework 5 and SQLite version 1.0.90.0. This project works fine. However now there are the version 1.0.91.0 of SQLite that allows to use EF6 so I would like to use it.

I hava had installed the version 1.0.90.0 that install the design components in visual studio. I did search for unistall it and install the new version, but I don't find the way to do it, so I install the new version directly.

Later I delete all the references in my project of EF 5 and SQLite 1.0.90.0 and delete in my appconfig all the configuration.

Later I went to the nuget manager and I istall the SQLite v1.0.91.0. This detects that I need to install EF6 and install it, the version 6.0.2 of EF and add into the appconfig the provider and factory. Also add the references to the dlls in the project.

It seems that all is ok, burn when I go to create the edmx model, in the wizzard, I have only one option in the EF selection, the versión 6, but this is in gray (disabled) because it says that I have the last versión of EF but there are not a database provider compatible with this version of EF.

Have I done something wrong? How can I use SQLite with EF6?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510096/entity-framework-6-sqlite You can check Brice's steps here.

Comment: With the configuration file of this link I don't have his problem but says me that the System.Data.SQLite.EF6 is not register in the computer. I have installed the vs2013 design components and if I am not wrong, this register the libraries in the computer.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía - did you build the project after adding the SqlLite provider and before trying creating the edmx?