# SQLite and Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, sqlite

I have already visited those questions and problem solving links:

- [Entity Framework 6 + SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510096/entity-framework-6-sqlite)
- [Visual Studio 2013 say me Entity framework that the provider of SQLite is not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21823719/visual-studio-2013-say-me-entity-framework-that-the-provider-of-sqlite-is-not-fo)
- http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Rebuilding%20EF%20providers%20for%20EF6

I downloaded and installed the 1.0.92.0 SQLite Release Package from here http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

I create a new project (class library) in visual studio 2013. 
Through NuGet I add `System.Data.SQLite` (which on itself also adds Core, EF6 and LINQ), EF is also installed.

I create the new ADO.NET Entity Data Model, I generate from the DB, select my DB (testing connection - ok), I go to "Which version of Entity Framework do you want to use?" and I have only the option "6" which is unavailable and it says:

> Your project references the latest version of EF, however, an EF
>   database provider compatible with this version could not be found for
>   you data connection.

From what I have read, `1.0.92.0` should work with EF6 (even from `1.0.91.0`)

Comment: Did you rebuild the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done somé testing, and the SQLite support for the EF Tools appear to be completely broken, due to an incomplete implementation of the EF6 provider, which is also not installed in GAC. I would file an issue with the System.Data.SQLite developers

Comment: I needed that within 1-2 hours so it was useless for me.. Anyway this particular answers seems to be THE answer at the moment.. hopefully it would change in the future.