# SQLite not an option using Generate Database Wizard with Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2022, .net-4.8

I am attempting to change the database provider for a project that uses Entity Framework 6.4.4 from SQL Server to SQLite.

I have the SQLite nuget package installed on the project as well as the SQLite toolbox extension for VS2022. The project already has an `.edmx` file describing the database I would like to build. However, when I attempt to generate the database (via the Generate Database Wizard), SQLite is not available as a Data Source:

[image: Change Data Source Image]

I have read some posts about this issue and many advise installing the packages found here: https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/news.wiki

However, these packages do not include Visual Studio 2022, nor do they include .NET Framework 4.8.

I am able to create and manage SQLite databases via the SQLite Toolbox extension, but that functionality does not extend to the DB Creation Wizard.

My `app.config` is shown below. This should be looking for SQLite as a DB provider. I've made sundry edits to this file to no effect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    
        <section name="entityFramework" 
                 type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" 
                      type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="PSRtestDB.db"
             connectionString="data source=C:\Users\adamsc\Documents\TEMP\PSR DB\PSRtestDB.db"
             providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

The question below appears to imply that this simply can't be done, that the DB must be created manually if SQLite is to be used. I would appreciate confirmation on that from anyone who has experience in this area.

[Entity Framework 6 not creating tables in SQLite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304899/entity-framework-6-not-creating-tables-in-sqlite-database)

I am stymied and unsure what to try. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have som advise here: https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/wiki/EF6-workflow-with-SQLite-DDEX-provider

Comment: @ErikEJ, thank you for the post. The link included steps that I had not previously tried. Unfortunately, while I did get the SQLite EF6 provider in the GAC and install all necessary packages, the provider still is not an option to connect to a new database. It seems like if the tool registers as available in one place it ought to be available elsewhere. Any ideas of where to look for errors? Thank you.